# Listen to user.emailVerified state in firebase with React Native(Expo)

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, email-verification

**Note:** This question was marked as duplicate and there was three questions linked, but they are not similar to my question. My question is how can I take a certain action when the email of the user gets verified in Firebase with React Native. The questions that were linked doesn't answer my question, one of them are for flutter (yet it doesn't show how to resolve my issue), the other two show that `user.emailVerified` is still false even after the user clicks the verification link in their email, which is definitely not my problem.

Now let me tell you what I want to do, in my App I want to implement a sign up system with email/password. Whenever the user creates an account, I am sending a verification email containing a verification link to their email using firebase like the following:

```js
sendEmailVerification(user);
```

Right after that, I am redirecting the user to another screen which says that the user should verify their email. In the new screen I have a few functionalities like, `change email address` and `resend verification email`. Whenever the user verifies their email by clicking the verification link in the email, I want to navigate to the home page. But my issue is, I do not know when the user clicks the verification email.

**Here's what I have tried**
Some people have suggested me to use `user.reload()` after a certain time period. But here is a con, Imagine I am calling `user.reload()` after every 20 seconds. But, if the user clicks the verification link after 21 seconds then the user will have to wait 19 seconds for the app to know that their email was verified. The user is most unlikely to wait that time period and they might end up uninstalling the app.

So, I will be grateful if you show me a code example about how can I achieve this or you can show me a sample source code in GitHub which does something similar to me.

Answer (score 1):

> Whenever the user clicks on the verification link, I want the app to navigate to the next screen.

The `emailVerified` property will be set to `true` only if the user clicks the link that is received in the email. The problem is that there is no callback for that, so you'll have to wait until the user clicks the link in the email, and right after that refresh their sign-in credentials. You can achieve this either by signing in again or calling the [reload()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#reload) method. These are the only options that you have in order to set the `emailVerified` property to `true`.

Besides that, `onAuthStateChanged` is not triggered when the `emailVerified` property turns to `true`

Comment: How do I know if the user has clicked the verification link? Can you show a code example?

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, there is no callback for that. None of the listeners fire when the user clicks the verification link. So you should sign in again or call the [reload()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#reload) method.

Comment: If you have a hard time implementing the [reload()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#reload) method, then please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: What I actually mean is, how do I know when to reload()? I might call it after 20 seconds  but the user might click the link after 30 seconds.

Comment: I have explained in this [resource](https://medium.com/p/bd70ca56ea91) how to do it.

Comment: Hey there. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: The resource you told me about is for Flutter, not for React Native.

Comment: It's about the idea of how to solve that not about the programming language.